# Is it possible to correlate on multiple properties in Rebus?

Tags: rebus

Is it possible to correlate on multiple properties in Rebus? Or I should combine them into one correlation Id?

Thanks

Yin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine the saga part of it into one correlation value that is stored in a single field on the saga, but you're free to do method calls and string concatenation and whatnot for generating a correlation value out of the incoming message.

The reason is technical: The saga data property path is an `Expression<Func<TSagaData, object>>` that [gets reflected into a string](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/Correlator.cs#L42) that can be used by Rebus to generate a suitable query to a database, whereas the correlator is just using a `Func<TMessage, object>` [to extract a correlation value](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/Correlator.cs#L16) from your message.